# writing a scrpy spider , something get wrong

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my code , I don't know how to fix it:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\shang\404.py", line 122
    for 'post-header' in response.css('header.post-header'):
       ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is trying to assign the result of a function call (`response.css()`) to a string literal (`'post-header'`), which makes no sense.

You need to assign to a variable instead:

```
for x in response.css('header.post-header'):
    # do something with x
```

Note that the variable name `x` is just an arbitrary label, so you could also use a more readable name like `post_header`:

```
for post_header in response.css('header.post-header'):
    # do something with post_header
```

Comment: Thanks very much !

Comment: No problem Peter. If you found this answer helpful, you can `upvote` and/or `accept` it - that will encourage others to help you in the future

Comment: Sorry , I don't know how to upvote or accept it ,could you teach me ?

Comment: `To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in`

Comment: To upvote `Click the large up arrow to the left of a post`

Comment: Thanks , I did it !